# Play audio on server hardware

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, audio, javafx, jmf

i'm programming an alarm clock based on Java EE and wildfly (previously did it on tomcat)
requirements:
- control from android app (self developed)
- via rest the alarm times are set (done)
- scheduling via ManagedScheduledExecutorService (done)
- playing audio file ON SERVER HARDWARE (is in my room with sound system attached)

tomcat: worked correctly with JMF javax.media.Player
problem: no concurrency utilities in tomcat

wildfly: getting NoPlayerException with JMF and javafx Media crashes baaadly

is it even possibly to play and "control" audio on native sound card with Java EE?

Any suggestions or experiences?

(thought about playing file by executing external command like ffmpeg or mpg123, but want to try it the java-way)

Server: linux debian 8
Application server: wildfly 9

EDIT:
added jmf to pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1e</version>
</dependency>
```

simple experimental class, executed in a scheduled task:

```
public class SoundPlayer {

    protected Logger logger;
    protected String DIR_SOUND;
    protected String track;
    protected File soundFile;

    public SoundPlayer(String audio) {      
        DIR_SOUND = "/Users/rome/.alarm/sound/";
        try {
            File track = new File(DIR_SOUND + audio);
            player = Manager.createPlayer(track.toURI().toURL());
            player.addControllerListener(new SoundPlayerListener());
        } catch (NoPlayerException | IOException e) {
            log()
        }

    public void play() {
        player.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }


    private class SoundPlayerListener implements ControllerListener, LineListener {

        @Override
        public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent event) {
            logger.debug("Event received");
            if (event instanceof StopEvent) {
                logger.debug("Stop!!!");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            logger.debug("Event received!");    
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
2015-08-27 07:46:49 ERROR stderr:71 - javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :file:/Users/rome/.alarm/sound/default.wav
2015-08-27 07:46:49 ERROR stderr:71 -   at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForContent(Manager.java:1412)
2015-08-27 07:46:49 ERROR stderr:71 -   at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:417)
```

JavaFX:
added jboss-deployment-structure.xml with all the javafx path entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="javafx/animation" />
                    <path name="javafx/application" />
                    <path name="javafx/beans" />
                    <path name="javafx/beans/binding" />
                    <path name="javafx/beans/property" />
                    <path name="javafx/beans/property/adapter" />
                    <path name="javafx/beans/value" />
                    <path name="javafx/collections" />
                    <path name="javafx/collections/transformation" />
                    <path name="javafx/concurrent" />
                    <path name="javafx/css" />
                    <path name="javafx/embed/swing" />
                    <path name="javafx/embed/swt" />
                    <path name="javafx/event" />
                    <path name="javafx/fxml" />
                    <path name="javafx/geometry" />
                    <path name="javafx/print" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/canvas" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/chart" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/control" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/control/cell" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/effect" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/image" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/input" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/layout" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/media" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/paint" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/shape" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/text" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/transform" />
                    <path name="javafx/scene/web" />
                    <path name="javafx/stage" />
                    <path name="javafx/util" />
                    <path name="javafx/util/converter" />
                    <path name="netscape/javascript" />
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

unfortunately, i don't have the code anymore, but it was also few lines long, initializing Media... I also tried Clip with no avail 
something like this:

```
JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();
Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

and got this error:
[image: java error]

thx in advance

Comment: Execute an external command.

Comment: The JEE environment includes all the normal JRE, meaning you could play sound by using *javax.sound* or any library building on top of it. What have you tried?

Comment: @Durandal: i've edited my post and added some code samples. thx for looking at it

Comment: Oops, you got a crash of the VM there. That should not happen, so there must be a bug in the VM or a driver. Personally I would try the old *update everything* to current version first before looking any further (But be wary that this could always make things worse or trigger a load of other issues). If you still get VM crashes then try finding out what exactly the circumstances for the crash are (a test program triggering the bug if possible) and file a bug report (either for debian or oracle, hopefully the crash log will have a hint what crashed).

Comment: damn. I dismissed the idea of using java fx, it was a very bad idea. i think i've been mistreatin' too many components :-) so I tried AudioSystem once again and found out that the exception was coming from a not initialized ExecutorService :-| i fixed my project and now it is working just fine. i will post the snippet, just in case it could help someone. thx

Answer (score 1):

My bad, the exception was somewhere else. it works fine with java AudioSystem. here a snippet:

```
// ...
protected File soundFile;
protected Clip clip;
protected LineListener listener;

public void play() {
    soundFile = new File(DIR_SOUND + audiotitle);
    AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.addLineListener(listener);
    clip.open(in);
    clip.start();
    // ...
}
// ...
```